# Add view in the bottom of Django modeladmin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, markdown

I have a blog made with Django where I write posts in markdown. I would like to add a view in the bottom of the admin page for each instance of the class Entry (my blog post class) such that I can get a preview of what the markdown looks like, while I'm writing. Just as you get a preview here on Stack Overflow when you create a new post.

I already have an admin class extending ModelAdmin:

```
class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
   list_display = ('title','created')
   prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
```

Is it possible to modify ModelAdmin further, such that it loads a certain html file (blogpost.html) and shows it in the bottom of the admin page?

I made a picture to show exactly what I mean:

[image]

NB: I know there are various tools such as Django admin plus, that allows one to add views to the admin interface, but not for each instance of an object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `markdownx` for that:

```
pip install django-markdownx
```

**project settings.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS = 
    #. . . .
    'markdownx',
]
```

**project urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    #[...]
    url(r'^markdownx/', include('markdownx.urls')),
]
```

and then collect `static` files.

```
python3 manage.py collectstatic
```

**your models.py**

```
from markdownx.models import MarkdownxField

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = MarkdownxField()
```

**your app admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from markdownx.admin import MarkdownxModelAdmin
from .models import MyModel


admin.site.register(MyModel, MarkdownxModelAdmin)
```

This should work.

Comment: Thank you very much for the comprehensive answer. It is not quite what I would like to do. As I have MathJax interpreting LaTeX code from the output of markdownx, this way of making a preview will not show the post exactly as it is presented to the user. Do you know if it's possible to append a view of the actual page in bottom of the admin page?

Comment: @Math_kv, You can use CKEditor for that. That will interpret `mathjx` also.